# Parse save all data from class to local Database

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Parse : How to save all data from class to Offline Database (`SQLite`)  in android ?
i try to get all data found in specific class and save it in local database to use it when phone without internet connection .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What part are you stuck on? What have you tried? Right now, the question reads like "please write code for me to do this" which presumably isn't what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `SQLite` database table and write method for inserting data into your table after parsing.As simple as that.Refer [this](http://codetheory.in/working-sqlite-database-crud-operations-android/) for learning `SQLite` operations

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) for parsing and converting them to objects. To save this data in database, you can use the [greendao](http://greendao-orm.com/) library for saving and fetching back.